# UIScrollView with UITableVIew and smaller increments than contents size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView as a subview of a CustomView that redefine the method hitTest, so the scrollview can scroll in smaller increments (the width of the scrollview is smaller than the window size) and I can also scroll inside the UITableView.

But the problem is that I only can scroll the table clicking inside the UISCrollView that is centered in the window with approx 1/3 of its height.

The UIScrollView is not wrapping it content, so it's displayed correctly. The problem is just the "click area" of the subview UITableView

Thanks!